# When is it safe to shoot on 7 with 2 imposters?

Tags: among-us

In what circumstances is it safe to shoot on 7 with 2 imposters?

If you get it wrong on 7 and shoot, you normally lose the game (assuming the people playing with you know how to play). Are there circumstances where this is okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really only 2 reasons (that I know of) where you should shoot on 7:

- **You know 100% one of the imposters.** For example, if like 5 people saw someone vent/kill it is safe to shoot (if more than two people cannot confirm, it is **not** 100%, don't shoot).
- **The lights are off.** If the lights are off (on any map), you can vote out who is most sus. Then have the lobby camp the button and 1-3 people who you most trust turn on the lights. This gives you a free shot as someone will die anyway, and is sometimes your best bet at winning.

Remember you have to shoot on 5/6.

Comment: I’m still gonna accept this answer because it states **when** it is okay to shoot, and the other answer just repeats something said here (even though this is the most downvoted answer).

Comment: I do not agree with the lights are off thing. The problem with voting out on 7 is pretty big that, by the maths, if you miss and the 2 traitors kill, they win. The Lights are off thing does not prevent a double kill from happening afterwards.

Comment: @Fredy31 yes it does for this reason: You cannot achieve a double kill with lights off, how would you? If you need 1 kill, one could screw with lights while the other waits for cooldown but you cannot screw with lights and wait for your cooldown at the same time. How do you expect to achieve a double kill? Your cooldown freezes when any menus are open.

Comment: Well they could both stay off lights and have it still countdown. you only need 1 person on lights to fix them, and it could be anyone. So if any of the 4  innocents left are doing it, well both traitors may wait their timer and kill on count down.

Comment: @Fredy31 I’m extremely confused aa to what you’re saying, I’ve done this so many times before. **As long as crews rush to the lights panel and fix it within 20-something seceonds (which is hard not to do), the imposters *cannot* kill, as someone is camping the button.** I don’t really know how else to explain it, there’s no way the imposters can kill unless the kill time is set to like 5 seconds.

Comment: Really depends on the rules of the lobby. Most times I play the after meeting kill countdown is longer than the emergency countdown. the lights do not change that.

Comment: @Fredy31 yes. You have more proven *my* point. Since the kill cooldown is longer than the meeting cooldown, you can call a meeting before dying. I think you're just not exactly understanding what I'm saying. If Bob flicks on the lights right away and Jim calls the button once they're on, the imposter cannot kill.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with throwing someone out of the airlock on 7 is that since there are only 6 people left, if you miss and there is still 2 impostors they only have to both kill once and they win. (it falls on a 2-2 tie, which gives the win to the impostors). Their kill countdown will probably come up before you can call a meeting and throw one out, and at that point its rare you will be in a position to finish tasks in time. So if the impostors get that they can win on a double, they will just wait their countdown, kill the first person in their way and they win.

So thats why its said that **its a bad idea to throw someone out on 7**. Same thing applies on eliminating someone on 4 when there is 1 impostor. (Or I guess throwing someone out on 10 if there are 3 impostors, but never saw a 3 impostor lobby.)

But its not a complete no no. **If you have an impostor dead to rights**, then shoot on 7 all day. But if you have no idea, if you are on 7 its not a right time to just eliminate on a guess.

With all that being said: if you throw out on a 7 and do miss, split up in two groups of 3. Then if both traitors are in the same group, they can only kill one player and if they are in different groups, there is a player to report quickly if a kill happens.

TLDR: If you know for sure that you have 2 traitors remaining, it is a bad idea to vote out on 7. Except if you got a traitor for sure. The don't vote on 7 rule is just because its riskier than the usual vote out.

Answer (score 1):

You should only **ever** shoot on 7 when more than 2 people know (100% Proof. (eg. Saw them vent, saw them go with a person who then died, saw them kill but didn't have a chance to report the body)) one of the Impostors

Answer (score 1):

**It is sometimes safe to kill on 7.**

---

**Risks That You Take**
There are non-specific risks that you are taking when you kill on 7:

- **Lazy Sussers.**
  There are lazy crewmates who sus anyone possible, like when you and your imposter teammate get a double kill, they can random sus, and your chances are high.
- **Immune Players.**
  The shorter the kills get, the higher the immune players be, unless you kill them. They can sus you for not doing "Medbay Scan", "Empty Garbage", or "Shields".
- **Lying Disadvantages.**
  If you vote out someone before 7 and lied, the crewmates can sus you.

  ---

  **Advantages You Can Use**
  Even if it isn't good to vote on 7, there are a few advantages you can use to kill on 7:
- **Body Hiding.**
  You can kill players in specific "Hide and Seek" places, leaving more time for your cooldown to reset and getting the win. (Risk)
- **Unique Sussing.**
  You can sus players in a unique way like: "He says we shouldn't vote on 7! He is sus and not talking anymore!" "He went into elec after voting! Only an imp would do that!"
- **Reporting Bodies Immediately.**
  If you kill someone and report their body immediately, you might gain 20% of your crewmates' trust and say that someone is sus and that you reported a body to take a risk of voting an imposter out.

---

#### Demo Stories

To prove that this information tips is correct, let's play 2 demo games, one negative from the disadvantages and one from the benefits.

**Story 1:**
There are 5 crewmates left, there are 2 imposters. A imposter kills in electrical. The body is reported.

**You are Yellow, and you are an imposter.**

**Red:** Yellow is sus let's vote him and Orange out.

**Purple:** Hold on, Red! Your sussing without any proof. So, let's see, Yellow lied about Lime killing Cyan, and we all did visual tasks. It has to be them and Orange left.

**You and Orange get ejected into space.**
**Story 2:**
5 Crewmates left, 2 imposters.
**You kill in Upper Engine in the top left corner.**
**Your teammate kills in Admin and immediately reports the body.**

**You:** It's Red. He isn't talking, he hasn't done a visual task, and he is nowhere to be found!

**Purple:** Okay, let's eject Red.

**You and Orange win.**

---

**Conclusion**
I hope this convinced you that you should sometimes kill on 7, and sometimes not.

Comment: To be honest public games aren't ever like this and just ends up being who yells louder or types the most.